# Spring boot JPA - Custom Repository for multiple Entity

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I've got some difficulties with my JPA Rest Project.
I have build my repositories for each of my entity (my tables in my database), and it works fine.
For example, a part of my entity "Personne" :

```
@Entity
public class Personne {
private Long id;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private Date dateNaissance;
private String telDomicile;
private String telPortable;
private String telAutre;
private String telCommentaire;
private String fax;
private String mail;
private String commentaire;
private Timestamp dateSuppr;
private String sexe;
private Patient patientById;
private Adresse adresseByAdresseId;

@Id
@JsonProperty(value = "dataId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

And myRepository with a @Query :

```
@Transactional
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "personne", path = "personne", excerptProjection = InlinePersonne.class)
public interface PersonneRepo extends JpaRepository<Personne, Long> {
@Query("from Personne p where p.nom = ?1 and p.prenom = ?2")
public Personne customRequest(String nom, String prenom);
}
```

My problem : the return result is always a type "Personne".

I would like to make a native request that sends me back an object, with customized properties.

Example of the wished return :

```
{object :
    {name : String,
    surname : String,
    age : int },
    adresse :{
        city : String,
        street : String
    }
}
```

Is it possible  to do that ?
I really need it because I have to make complex requests on many tables.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [interface-base projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

First you create interfaces that reflect the fields you need:

```
interface PersonSummary {

  String getName();
  String getSurename();
  int getAge();

  AddressSummary getAddress();

  interface AddressSummary {
    String getCity();
    String getStreet();
  }
}
```

Then you indicate your custom query what interface it needs to extend and instantiate to populate the information:

```
public interface PersonneRepo extends JpaRepository<Personne, Long> {
    // All your other abstract method

    // Brand new query
    @Query("Select p.name, p.surname, p.age, p.city, p.street from Personne p where p.nom = ?1 and p.prenom = ?2")
    public PersonSummary customRequest(String nom, String prenom);
}
```

You  would be receiving an object like this:

```
{
  name : String,
  surname : String,
  age : int,
  address :{
    city : String,
    street : String
  }
}
```

You would need to test how flexible is this functionality in the terms of the composition complexity of the object you want to receive.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I know projections, but for what I need, I think it will be too complicated to use them.
Indeed, I have to make a request on a lot of tables (8 tables), and projections don't seem to be the best to do that.

Comment: It works fine ! Thanks a lot !
I just forget to set nativeQuery = true in my @Query...